# (int) php and mysql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I understand that the safest way to protect your website from SQL injection is to use Prepared Statements. But how does someone can go around this if user input is converted to a number?

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: That this particular instance is secure doesn't mean you should skip prepared statements. Using prepared statements *always* isn't hard with the right DB class/ORM, and using it **all** the time means you're a lot less likely to forget to sanitize. It's kinda like wearing a seat belt - you might drive safely 99% of the time, but it's still good to wear.

Comment: @ceejayoz So true and well said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *But how does someone can go around this if user input is converted to a number?*

Simply put, they can't, **end of story/hits brick wall**. Since it's been casted as an [integer](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), it cannot be modified or manipulated from thereon.

Only *you* have that power to modify it, if you wanted/had to.

For example:

```
$string = "String";
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
echo $new_value = $string . "" . $id;
```

Producing `String123`.

A `var_dump($new_value);` will produce `string(9) "String123"`.

But now, that would be a string, so you didn't want that, but it's just to show you what *can* be done, after the fact.

Since an SQL injection usually contains characters such as `'`, `-` or `DELETE` or anything else that isn't an integer and passed into by a potential hacker, the statement will be rejected.

`file.php?id=123` and modified in the URL such as `file.php?id=String'); DROP TABLE USERS; --` will not "pass GO", *as it were.*

What you could do is to check if what is being passed in the array is indeed an integer.

There are a few functions to check for this.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php
- https://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php
- [`filter_input()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) with the FILTER_VALIDATE_INT filter
  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

However, using a prepared statement would also be beneficial. Both the mysqli_ and PDO apis offer this.

- https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

When using for instance the mysqli_ api and then using something such as:

[`bind_param("i", $id)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (the `i` for "integer"). Even if someone did manage to pass something other than an integer, mysql will still refuse to let it go through, since it was also casted as an integer through the binded argument.

Yet, if that were `bind_param("s", $id)` - (the "s" for "string"), then that could be a different ballgame.

PDO has this also, being `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

With that said; stick to using a prepared statement, regardless.

Comment: @Rammy I noticed you posted a comment here earlier and when I came to read it, you deleted it and was about to respond to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that i'm asking too much. You spend enough time answering my first question. :)

Comment: @Rammy Well.. swing it by me and I'll see what I can do; I have a bit of time on my hands right now but not for too too long.

Comment: Which one is better to use in the MySQL statement for integer "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'" or "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id" ? I guess first one is treated as a string and the second one as a integer or it doesn't matter and both are good?

Comment: @Rammy Both do the same thing. However, that would be a different story if it were used in a function such as `IN()` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx where and if the `id` value is indeed an integer and the column type would fail, since it cannot be quoted.